# Как перебросить параметр закрытия окна из Модели в Презентер?

Tags: c#

```
private void MainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            MainFormClosing?.Invoke(this, (FormClosingEventArgs)EventArgs.Empty);
        }
```

При закрытии окна выдает ошибку, Не удается преобразовать EventArgs к FormClosingEventArgs

Comment: А такой код  не сработает так, как вам нужно? MainFormClosing?.Invoke(this, null);

Comment: Мне параметр нужен, чтобы его использовать, продолжить закрытие или отменить

Comment: Но вроде как для целей отмены закрытия достаточно в MainForm_FormClosing() постаить e.Cancel=true; - ну, то есть, преобразовывать тип для этого не нужно, и Invoke не нужен

Comment: Мне надо это на Презенторе обрабатывать

Comment: Тогда я прошу прощения за предыдущие тупые советы, но, может, вы тогла к вопросу тег про презентер добаите?

Comment: Да, надо добавить

Comment: Гм, но есть же `FormClosingEventArgs.Empty`

Comment: А кроме того, есть же готовый параметр `e`. Передавайте в `Invoke` его.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Да, я так и хочу сделать, но при выполнении программы, когда я ее закрываю, выдается ошибка -> Нельзя привезти EventArgs к FormClosingEventArgs
        {
            MainFormClosing?.Invoke(this, FormClosingEventArgs.Empty);
        }  **вот так не компилируется**

Comment: `public event FormClosingEventHandler MainFormClosing;` проброс

Answer (score 0):

```
private void MainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            MainFormClosing?.Invoke(this, e);
        }
```

> А кроме того, есть же готовый параметр e. Передавайте в Invoke его. –
> Alexander Petrov